# Group homomorphism induced by another homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I need to prove a theorem that if $\phi: G\to H$ is some homomorphism, $M\leq H$ $\phi^{-1}(M) := \{g\in G:\phi(g)\in K\}$, $M \trianglelefteq H$, then $\phi$ induces an injective homomorphism $G/\phi^{-1}(M)\to H/M$.

(I've already proved that $\phi^{-1}(M) \leq G$ and $\phi^{-1}(M)\trianglelefteq G$).

I'm willing to prove the theorem stated above, but I don't know what it means when a homomorphism induces another homomorphism. Didn't find anything about this subject in *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote (looked in the Glossary as well). I'm wondering if someone could please give me a good recommendation of what to read on this subject (I'm a beginner in Group Theory).

Comment: In math, inducing means to create (by way of some other operation). In your case, the fact that you have a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ gives rise to a homomorphism (you don't know what it is *a priori*) between $G/\phi^{-1}(M)$ and $H/M$.

Comment: All "induces" means is something like "under the given conditions, there is a natural or obvious definition of the thing in question". So given your situation, how would you define the induced homomorphism? (There aren't very many choices).

Comment: If I'm correct, then $G/\phi^{-1}(M)$ is a quotient group where $\phi^{-1}(M)$ consists of one element, which is a set in $G$ (pullback of M).

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: So inducing an injective homomorphism would mean that we're taking elements of G "via" modulo $\phi^{-1}(M)$ and then trying to get them to $H$ modulo $M$?

Comment: Yeah that's the right way to think about it. What's sort of happening is that you're lifting the action of $\phi$ strictly from $G$ (and mapping to $H$) to a quotient. That's one fairly common way to induce maps. There are others, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In math, inducing means to create (by way of some other operation). In your case, the fact that you have a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ gives rise to a homomorphism (you don't know what it is *a priori*) between $G/\phi^{-1}(M)$ and $H/M$.

I'll give you a hint/primer so that you can better understand exactly what is going on. Induced maps/morphisms/etc can be quite confusing at first since they take a trained eye to spot and understand.

First you have to show that there is some function between $G/\phi^{-1}(M)$ and $H/M$ before you can even show it is a homomorphism. The obvious question is: what *is* that map? Well $G/\phi^{-1}(M)$ is a set of equivalence classes of the form $g.\phi^{-1}(M)$. Likewise, $H/M$ is a set of equivalence classes of the form $h.M$ which obviously contains elements of the form $\phi(g).M$.

What is a nice map between these two sets? Using $\phi$, the *reasonable* map would be to send $g.\phi^{-1}(M)$ to $\phi(g).M$ since it seems to be the only way to truly pair things up between these two sets. This is where the "inducing" comes from. $\phi$ initially acted on $G$, but now it can be *sort of* thought of as acting on $G/\phi^{-1}(M)$.

Before you can prove that the above "function" from $G/\phi^{-1}(M)$ to $H/M$ is a homomorphism, you have to show that it is well-defined, meaning that it is constant on equivalence classes. If $g.\phi^{-1}(M) = g'.\phi^{-1}(M)$, then $f$ had better send them to the same thing in $H/M$ if it is actually a function - otherwise it sends the same element to two different images.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that $G/\phi^{-1}(M)$ and $H/M$ are sets of equivalence classes only if $\phi^{-1}(M)$ and $M$ are respective kernels of these groups?

Comment: They are always sets of equivalence classes since both $\phi^{-1}(M)$ and $M$ are subgroups. The quotients might not have any algebraic structure (if $M$ and $\phi^{-1}(M)$ are not normal), but they are always sets of equivalence classes.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$\phi^{-1}(M)$ is the kernel of the composition: $G\to H\to H/M$, where the last map is the canonical homomorphism $h\mapsto hM$.